# Concat Name and value in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My collection Document

```
 {
    "_id": 1,
    "location": "New York",
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "location": "New Jersey",
  }
```

Can i concat my name and value and produce an output something like this, =i think its not possible,but if there any workaround please help

```
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "New York location": "New York",
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "New Jersey location": "New Jersey",
  }
```

Comment: Just curious why do you need this?

Comment: command for rename:db.collection.update({}, {$rename: {'location': 'New York location'}}, false, true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be achieved in query but surely can be achieved by shell script

```
db.collection.find({'location':{$exists : true}}).forEach(function(doc){var newField = 
  doc.location+" location";db.collection.update(doc,{$rename :{'localtion':newField}});})
```

if your collection is really large and you are having memory issue, you can use limit multiple time

```
db.collection.find({'location':{$exists : true}}).limit(1000).forEach......
```

another variant of same process would be

```
db.collection.find({'location':{$exists : true}}).forEach(function(doc){var newField = 
   doc.location+" location"; doc[newField]=doc.location; delete doc.location;
    db.collection.save(doc);})
```